# Extract Parent Text without Children Text; Parsing HTML

Tags: python, selenium, loops, beautifulsoup

I have this small bit of a soup tag element that I pulled using `Selenium` & `BeautifulSoup`.

```
<footer>
    <p class="tags environment-tags">Environment:
      <span class="tag environment-tag">Desert</span>
    </p>
    <p class="source monster-source">Basic Rules
      <span class="page-number">, pg. 334</span>
    </p>
</footer>
```

I am trying to grab the Text from just the p elements, but every time I try it grabs the span as well. So far this is what I tried:

```
for p in Environment.findAll('p'):
    print(p.text)
```

I have also tried to extract the information using `.extract()` but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.contents` and access the 0th element:

```
for tag in soup.find_all("p"):
    print(tag.contents[0].strip())
```

Output:

```
Environment:
Basic Rules
```

---

Or with your attempt, you can remove the `<span>`'s using [`.extract()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) by:

```
for tag in soup.select("p span"):
    tag.extract()

print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```
<footer>
 <p class="tags environment-tags">
  Environment:
 </p>
 <p class="source monster-source">
  Basic Rules
 </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you this was a perfect answer. I didn't realize I could access elements using the contents method. Really cool to know. Thanks!